# iOS: Can I execute a method from within a block or is this incorrect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, objective-c-blocks

Two methods, one for upload and one for download, in `self.FfAppClient` work in a separate App where `uploadFile` and `downloadFile` are triggered by buttons on a view controller.  The user has a visual feedback when the upload completes and so may continue to press a button to download the file.

In the App below, I have tested that both `uploadFile` and `downloadFile` work on there own but when I use the code segment below, the upload sometimes fails and the download never works.

I am trying to wait till I know the upload is complete (`self.FfAppClient uploadFile` gives `success`) and then start the download.  Is this completely the wrong way to use blocks and more importantly, is there a reason that having `[self downloadImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ımage id=%d",entryID]];` within a block won't work?

```
- (void)uploadThenDownloadImage:(UIImage*)image usingImagePath:(NSString*)imagePath
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    [self.FfAppClient uploadFile:imagePath withContent:imageData success:^(id response) {
        NSInteger entryID = [[response objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        [self downloadImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ımage id=%d",entryID]];

   } failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Upload error: %@", error.description);
   }];

}

- (void)downloadImage:(NSString*)fileID
{
    [self.FfAppClient downloadFile:fileID success:^(id response) {
        NSString* suggested = [response objectForKey:@"suggested"];
        NSString* temp = [response objectForKey:@"temp"];
        [self moveTempFileNamed:suggested toIncomingFolderFromTemporaryLocation:temp];

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Download error: %@", error.description);
    } progress:^(float prc) {
        NSLog(@"Download amount: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"downloaded %.02f", prc]);
    }];
}
```

The error I get for the download part is:

```
-[FfAppClient URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]: error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x1383b500 {NSUnderlyingError=0x15370380 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

Sometimes, the upload also fails since the response, in the `success` block, gives a meaningless string for example `;8@c1jL2gZK3yWziVNuY-h1btzGG.t!u5zoRW2MV` instead of something that refers to the name of the picture on the server.

Is there another way to implement this or reason why my code is failing?

**

### EDIT: The `uploadFile` and `downloadFile` methods:

**

```
- (void)uploadFile:(NSString *)filename withContent:(NSData*)content success:(FfSuccessBlock)successBlock failure:(FfFailBlock)failBlock
{
        if ( ![self isConnected] )
{
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Not connected" code:0 userInfo:nil];
    failBlock(error);
    return;
}

NSString *urlFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@", kFfPicsBasePath, kFfPutFileURL, kFfSubscriptionId];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [self signedRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlFormat] andMethod:@"POST" andParams:params];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSString* boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary+%08X%08X", arc4random(), arc4random()];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// Body part for the attachament. This is an image.
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"docfile", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:content];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

request.HTTPBody = body;

self.currentSuccessBlock = successBlock;
self.currentFailBlock = failBlock;
__block FfAppClient* me = self;

self->_resTask = [self->_resSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
    if ( !error )
    {
        if ( statusCode >= 400 )
        {
            NSString* bodyError = data ? [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] : [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"HTTP Error: %d", @"FfResourceHTTPErrorDomain description"), statusCode];
            NSDictionary *errorInfo =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:bodyError forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Failed URL" code:statusCode userInfo:errorInfo];
        }
        else if ( ![[response MIMEType] isEqualToString:@"application/json"] || [data length] == 0 )
        {
            NSString* bodyStr = data ? [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] : @"";
            NSString* bodyError = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"HTTP Content Type Error: %@/n%@", @"FfOResource2HTTPErrorDomain description"), [response MIMEType], bodyStr];
            NSDictionary *errorInfo =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:bodyError forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Failed URL" code:555 userInfo:errorInfo];
        }
    }
    id jsonResponse = nil;
    if ( !error )
    {
        jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    }
    if ( error )
    {
        data = nil;
        if ( me.currentFailBlock ) {
            __block NSError* blockError = error;
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ me.currentFailBlock( blockError ); });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( me.currentSuccessBlock )
        {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ me.currentSuccessBlock(jsonResponse); });
        }
    }
    me->_resTask = nil;
    [me clearBlocks];
}];
[self->_resTask resume];
}

- (void)downloadFile:(NSString *)fileId success:(FfSuccessBlock)successBlock failure:(FfFailBlock)failBlock progress:(FfProgressBlock)progress;
{
if ( ![self isConnected] )
{
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Not connected" code:0 userInfo:nil];
    failBlock(error);
    return;
}

NSString *urlFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@", kFfPicsBasePath, kFfGetFileURL, fileId];
NSLog(@"fileid: %@", fileId);
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [self signedRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlFormat] andMethod:@"GET" andParams:params];

NSLog(@"---> Request: %@", request);

[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];

self.currentSuccessBlock = successBlock;
self.currentFailBlock = failBlock;
self.currentProgressBlock = progress;

self->_resTask = [self->_resSession downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
[self->_resTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Well, a lot depends on what `FfAppClient uploadFile` and `FfAppClient downloadFile` actually do. You haven't shown the code for those methods, so who knows what's going on?

Comment: @matt Sure.  I posted the code for those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a memory management or multi-threading issue; calling methods from within blocks is fine, but maybe not what you are doing with `FfAppClient` here. Before the upload `_resTask` has fully finished, you are starting a download task that overwrites most ivars the still unfinished upload call has set (this may cause objects to be released) and that on another thread than the one the task is running on. One would probably have to perform a major rewrite of the `FfAppClient` code to make it safe, but here are two quick hacks you might try:

*1) Use two different `FfAppClient`'s if possible*

Note the `FfAppClientA` and `FfAppClientB` in the code below:

```
- (void)uploadThenDownloadImage:(UIImage*)image usingImagePath:(NSString*)imagePath
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    [self.FfAppClientA uploadFile:imagePath withContent:imageData success:^(id response) {
        NSInteger entryID = [[response objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        [self downloadImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ımage id=%d",entryID]];

   } failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Upload error: %@", error.description);
   }];
}

- (void)downloadImage:(NSString*)fileID
{
    [self.FfAppClientB downloadFile:fileID success:^(id response) {
        NSString* suggested = [response objectForKey:@"suggested"];
        NSString* temp = [response objectForKey:@"temp"];
        [self moveTempFileNamed:suggested toIncomingFolderFromTemporaryLocation:temp];

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Download error: %@", error.description);
    } progress:^(float prc) {
        NSLog(@"Download amount: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"downloaded %.02f", prc]);
    }];
}
```

*2) Dispatch async and allow the first task to complete fully before starting the second one*

As the success and failure blocks are dispached synchronously to main, try the following:

```
- (void)uploadThenDownloadImage:(UIImage*)image usingImagePath:(NSString*)imagePath
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    [self.FfAppClientA uploadFile:imagePath withContent:imageData success:^(id response) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
            NSInteger entryID = [[response objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
            [self downloadImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ımage id=%d",entryID]];
        });    
   } failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Upload error: %@", error.description);
   }];

}
```

Those are rather quick hacks than real solutions, though.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.  Actually the developer I am working with has changed the code so I cannot test your hacks but he basically said that yes, the first task must completely finish before the second so I think your second hack would have worked